# Dump C# class in log file

Tags: c#, .net, debugging, logging

Is there a way dump deux classes :

```
public class Person
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
    public List<Address> Addresses { get; set; } 
}

public class Address
{
    public string Street { get; set; }
    public int Number { get; set; }
    public int Zipcode { get; set; }
    public string Locality { get; set; }
}
```

I'd like have something like below. Do you think it's possible? How can I do this ?
Important, here it's a class Person, it's an exemple. I'd like to be able to user all my class with the same dump code

**Update 1**
I don't need only the "structure" but "structure" + data and the class are not Serializable

```
<Person>
        <FirstName></FirstName>
        <LastName></LastName>
        <Age></Age>
        <Addresses>
            <Address>
                <Street></Street>
                <Number></Number>
                <Zipcode></Zipcode>
                <Locality></Locality>
            </Address>
            <Address>
                <Street></Street>
                <Number></Number>
                <Zipcode></Zipcode>
                <Locality></Locality>
            </Address>      
        </Addresses>
    </Person>
```

Thanks

Comment: Of course, use reflection.  However, as it stands now, your question doesn't appear to show that you've put much effort into attempting to solve this problem yourself.

Comment: That would be more like [Serialization in XML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/58a18dwa.aspx)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To dump your class, I think it would be better to use real XmlSerialization than what you defined. It's almost the same, but Xml is standard.

```
public void SerializeObject<T>(T obj)
{
    using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter("your path"))
    {
        new XmlSerializer(typeof(T)).Serialize(sw, obj);
    }
}

public T DeserializeObject<T>()
{
    T obj;
    using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("your path"))
    {
        obj = (T)new XmlSerializer(typeof(T)).Deserialize(sr);
    }

    return obj;
}
```

You can use it like this :

```
Person p = new Person();
SerializeObject(p);
```

Here's what the output looks like, no modifications were made to your Person class (don't need any [Serializable] tags) :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Person xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <FirstName>f</FirstName>
  <LastName>l</LastName>
  <Age>50</Age>
  <Addresses>
    <Address>
      <Street>s</Street>
      <Number>1</Number>
      <Zipcode>1</Zipcode>
      <Locality>l</Locality>
    </Address>
    <Address>
      <Street>s2</Street>
      <Number>12</Number>
      <Zipcode>12</Zipcode>
      <Locality>l2</Locality>
    </Address>
  </Addresses>
</Person>
```

Comment: @Kris-I What do you mean "The classes are not serializable"? They're made of int and strings, of course they are. You don't even need to tag them as [Serializable()]

Answer (score 1):

If you need this particular xml formatting, then you can pretty easily achieve this with reflection.

You can write a method looking like:

```
public string DumpClass(object obj) {}
```

and in your method, just get the type of your object and then iterate recursively through its properties.

Or you can use the XmlSerializer, it won't be the same format, but it'll serialize your class to quite readable xml. (you have an example here: http://www.jonasjohn.de/snippets/csharp/xmlserializer-example.htm)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using [**XElement**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387089.aspx) to create this file as XML but then just save the string to a text file. Just put empty string `""` in place of where the variable would have been for every tag. You can also use [**xml serialization**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/182eeyhh.aspx) and write it to a file.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
[Serializable()]
[XmlRoot("Person")]
public class Person
{
    XmlElement("FirstName")]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    XmlElement("LastName")]
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    XmlElement("Age")]
    public int Age { get; set; }

    [XmlArray("Addresses")]
    [XmlArrayItem("Address", typeof(Address))]
    public List<Address> Addresses { get; set; } 
}

[Serializable()]
public class Address
{
    [XmlElement("Street")]
    public string Street { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("Number")]
    public int Number { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("Zipcode")]
    public int Zipcode { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("Locality")]
    public string Locality { get; set; }
}
```

To Serialize:

```
Person person = new Person();
XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Person));

StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(file_path);
serializer.Serialize(writer, person);
writer.Close();
```

To Deserialize:

```
XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Person));

StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(file_path);
Person person = (Person)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
reader.Close();
```